# Using Typescript classes with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to execute in NodeJS some code written in Typescript using classes.
To keep it brutally simple, I have the following class

```
export class AppToSayHello { 
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello my friend');
    }
}
```

and I would like to execute

```
node AppToSayHello.js
```

what I get though is an error saying

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Is there a way to make this work or should I just stick to plain JS?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

After some help, a bit more reading and some tests I have been able to make it work (launching `node main.js`) like this

***Class Main***

```
    import AppTSToSayHello = require('./appTSToSayHello');
    class Main {
        constructor() {
            var myHello = new AppTSToSayHello();
            myHello.sayHello();
        }
    }
    var main = new Main();

module.exports = main;
```

***Class AppTSToSayHello***

```
export class AppTSToSayHello { 
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello my friend');
    }
}

module.exports = AppTSToSayHello;
```

I am not sure though if I have done this 'according to the book' and there is a little annoying thing left: the compiler gives me an error 'Cannot use new with expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature'.
If some knows why and can suggest me a fix I would appreciate.
In any case thanks for the help. Now it works and this is fine.

Comment: What's the contents of the generated file?

Comment: There's probably some boilerplate code you need to use to wrap the Typescript class(es), specifically looks like SystemJS is a dependency (but I never tried Typescript so I don't really know). Read some docs.

Comment: My actual objective is to run a series of scripts that maintain a MongoDB and I do this via NodeJS using plain JS. It would be cool though to be able to leverage Typescript features, especially Classes and OO design. I hope this helps clarify my question

Comment: You've provided no details on how you actually build your TypeScript project, so all I can suggest is to make sure that the `module` compiler option is set to `commonjs`.